# `RuntimeError: Failed to allocate tensors` When using retrained object detection model on Google Coral

Tags: object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite, tpu, google-coral

I am trying to deploy an object detection model on Google Coral. I trained the model using the following [config file](https://gist.github.com/rsandler00/d3cc04912fcee6dd90cce03020f3e1a0), which I tried to closely match to the demo config file from the docker image described [here](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/#).

I successfully trained my model, then I ran the script `./convert_checkpoint_to_edgetpu_tflite.sh` seemingly successfully with the following output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /media/wwang/WorkDir/projects/SANATA/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /media/wwang/WorkDir/projects/SANATA/models/research/object_detection/anchor_generators/multiple_grid_anchor_generator.py:183: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
2019-09-12 11:15:11.539092: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-09-12 11:15:11.707588: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x68382b0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-09-12 11:15:11.707625: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-09-12 11:15:11.728473: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3298290000 Hz
2019-09-12 11:15:11.729431: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x68a1b90 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-09-12 11:15:11.729473: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-09-12 11:15:11.729783: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.635
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 10.73GiB freeMemory: 10.34GiB
2019-09-12 11:15:11.729823: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-09-12 11:15:11.732474: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-09-12 11:15:11.732509: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
2019-09-12 11:15:11.732523: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
2019-09-12 11:15:11.732730: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10057 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /media/wwang/WorkDir/projects/SANATA/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py:127: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
2019-09-12 11:15:15.451695: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-09-12 11:15:15.451741: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-09-12 11:15:15.451748: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
2019-09-12 11:15:15.451753: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
2019-09-12 11:15:15.451857: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10057 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /media/wwang/WorkDir/projects/SANATA/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py:232: convert_variables_to_constants (from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants
WARNING:tensorflow:From /media/wwang/WorkDir/projects/SANATA/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py:245: extract_sub_graph (from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph
2019-09-12 11:15:17.880135: I tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph.cc:317] Applying strip_unused_nodes
CONVERTING frozen graph to TF Lite file...
2019-09-12 11:15:19.959403: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-09-12 11:15:20.105331: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x3f28f50 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-09-12 11:15:20.105370: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-09-12 11:15:20.124476: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3298290000 Hz
2019-09-12 11:15:20.125267: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x3f92630 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-09-12 11:15:20.125297: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-09-12 11:15:20.125542: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.635
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 10.73GiB freeMemory: 10.34GiB
2019-09-12 11:15:20.125569: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-09-12 11:15:20.127390: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-09-12 11:15:20.127411: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
2019-09-12 11:15:20.127420: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
2019-09-12 11:15:20.127553: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10057 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
TFLite graph generated at model_exported/output_tflite_graph.tflite
```

Then I ran `edgetpu_compiler output_tflite_graph.tflite` also seemingly successfully with the following output:

```
Edge TPU Compiler version 2.0.258810407
INFO: Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.

Model compiled successfully in 383 ms.

Input model: model_exported/output_tflite_graph.tflite
Input size: 1.65MiB
Output model: output_tflite_graph_edgetpu.tflite
Output size: 2.33MiB
On-chip memory available for caching model parameters: 7.00MiB
On-chip memory used for caching model parameters: 2.11MiB
Off-chip memory used for streaming uncached model parameters: 0.00B
Number of Edge TPU subgraphs: 1
Total number of operations: 115
Operation log: output_tflite_graph_edgetpu.log

Model successfully compiled but not all operations are supported by the Edge TPU. A percentage of the model will instead run on the CPU, which is slower. If possible, consider updating your model to use only operations supported by the Edge TPU. For details, visit g.co/coral/model-reqs.
Number of operations that will run on Edge TPU: 114
Number of operations that will run on CPU: 1
See the operation log file for individual operation details.
```

And the following `output_tflite_graph_edgetpu.log` file:

```
Edge TPU Compiler version 2.0.258810407
Input: output_tflite_graph.tflite
Output: output_tflite_graph_edgetpu.tflite

Operator                       Count      Status

DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D              33         Mapped to Edge TPU
RESHAPE                        13         Mapped to Edge TPU
LOGISTIC                       1          Mapped to Edge TPU
CUSTOM                         1          Operation is working on an unsupported data type
ADD                            10         Mapped to Edge TPU
CONCATENATION                  2          Mapped to Edge TPU
CONV_2D                        55         Mapped to Edge TPU
```

Finally, I put my converted `output_tflite_graph_edgetpu.tflite` on the Coral, and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 224, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 221, in main
    run_app(add_render_gen_args, render_gen)
  File "/home/mendel/projects/DARTS/object_detection/edge_tpu_vision/edgetpuvision/apps.py", line 75, in run_app
    display=args.displaymode):
  File "/home/mendel/projects/DARTS/object_detection/edge_tpu_vision/edgetpuvision/gstreamer.py", line 243, in run_gen
    inference_size = render_overlay_gen.send(None)  # Initialize.
  File "main.py", line 154, in render_gen
    engines, titles = utils.make_engines(args.model, DetectionEngine)
  File "/home/mendel/projects/DARTS/object_detection/edge_tpu_vision/edgetpuvision/utils.py", line 53, in make_engines
    engine = engine_class(model_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/detection/engine.py", line 55, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 300, in __init__
    this = _edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.new_BasicEngine(*args)
RuntimeError: Failed to allocate tensors.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

PS: I realize this may be more suited for a git issue, but I am not sure where to post google-coral issues on git...

Comment: Are you trying to run this on Coral Dev Board or on USB TPU Accelerator ?

Comment: Coral dev board

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with the Coral board as well after following the tutorial to retrain an object detection model.

For me the issue was due to the compiler targeting a different runtime version than I had on the Coral board. On the Coral board, you can check the runtime version like this:

```
python3 -c "import edgetpu.basic.edgetpu_utils; print(edgetpu.basic.edgetpu_utils.GetRuntimeVersion())"
```

On my board the runtime version was **10** which is not the same as the default for the compiler which was **12**. If you indeed have the same issue then you can compile the model targeting this version using:

```
edgetpu_compiler --min_runtime_version 10 your_model.tflite
```

Source:
https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/compiler/#compiler-and-runtime-versions

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with the newest compiler and check back? I know there were a few bugs in the compiler it self which is fixed. Guide is here:
https://coral.withgoogle.com/news/updates-09-2019/

Comment: I can vouch for this as I had the same issue previously but had no problems at all after updating in late November last year.